# Pandas loc is returning series not df

Tags: python, pandas

The following code returns a series for y when I want a df. Ultimately I am pulling rows out of a larger raw df (df) to create a smaller df (Cand) of results. I have created Cand as the new empty df to be populated.

```py
Cand = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SR','Hits','Breaks'])

x = df.loc[df['Breaks'] == 0]
y = x.loc[x['Hits'].idxmax()]

Cand.append(y)
```

x is correctly reflected as a df, but y becomes a series and so does not populate Cand.

I have looked around but cannot find a similar problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the original data of df so this is a reproducible problem?

Comment: Here is the df for 'x'. I have not posted the original df as is quite big and not sure this will help.

 SR_Level Hits Breaks
0 0.874 0 0
1 0.87414 1 0
49 0.8808600000000014 4 0

Comment: That includes an index column which goes 0, 1, 49

Comment: What do you *expect as your desired input*? In addition, please post a sample of your dataframe  [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51810322/edit) rather than as a comment.

Comment: Hi jpp, sorry I will edit my question next time to add data. Thanks for your help. fyi answer below has solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue would not be that you aren't passing a DataFrame to `append()`, but that `.append()` here is not in-place; try reassigning the return of `append()` to `Cand` as `Cand = Cand.append(y)`, given that `append` *returns* your initial DataFrame + *other* (Cand + **y**, in this case).

*Side Note:*

You can return a DataFrame from [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by using double square brackets.
Example: `y = x.loc[[x['Hits'].idxmax()]]`

Comment: Thank you qzdl, this worked perfectly. I did not consider that I could pass the series into the df, and overlooked Cand = Cand.append. All the best.